Odoo CORS Access Issue
I'm having trouble executing a AJAX call to a controller that belongs to Odoo.sh, I'm testing from my localhost.
try {
const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/check_available_venues`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        from_date: start,
                        to_date: end,
                        booking_individuals_total
                    })
                });
            // Log the full response for debugging
            console.log('Response status:', response.status);
            console.log('Response headers:', Object.fromEntries(response.headers.entries()));

            const responseText = await response.text(); // Get text before potentially parsing as JSON
            console.log('Response body:', responseText);

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}, body: ${responseText}`);
            }

            const data = JSON.parse(responseText);

            // Rest of your existing code...
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Venue check error details:', {
                message: error.message,
                stack: error.stack
            });
            this._toastMessage(`Failed to check available venues: ${error.message}`, 'error');
            noNextStep = true;
        }

This is the controller I'm trying to access:
@http.route("/check_available_venues", type='json', auth="none", methods=['POST', 'GET'], website=True, csrf=False,
            cors='*')
def check_available_venues(self, from_date, to_date, booking_individuals_total):

While this is the error I'm getting:


"I'm testing from my localhost" - is that http://localhost/... or file:///...

You're missing the whole preflight step. It requires 'OPTIONS' method to be allowed, and server should respond 200 on preflight request.

Why not using the standard odoo api: xmrpc (execute_kw...) ?
